# Perform multiple search-and-replaces on the colnames of a dataframe

Tags: regex, r, dataframe, batch-rename

I have a dataframe with 95 cols and want to batch-rename a lot of them with simple regexes, like the snippet at bottom, there are ~30 such lines. Any other columns which don't match the search regex must be left untouched.

**** Example: names(tr) = c('foo', 'bar', 'xxx_14', 'xxx_2001', 'yyy_76', 'baz', 'zzz_22', ...) ****

I started out with a wall of 25 gsub()s - crude but effective:

```
names(tr) <- gsub('_1$',    '_R', names(tr))
names(tr) <- gsub('_14$',   '_I', names(tr))
names(tr) <- gsub('_22$',   '_P', names(tr))
names(tr) <- gsub('_50$',   '_O', names(tr))
... yada yada
```

@Joshua: mapply doesn't work, turns out it's more complicated and impossible to vectorize. names(tr) contains other columns, and when these patterns do occur, you cannot assume all of them occur, let alone in the exact order we defined them. Hence, try 2 is:

```
pattern <- paste('_', c('1','14','22','50','52','57','76','1018','2001','3301','6005'), '$', sep='')
replace <- paste('_', c('R','I', 'P', 'O', 'C', 'D', 'M', 'L',   'S',   'K',   'G'),         sep='')
do.call(gsub, list(pattern, replace, names(tr)))
Warning messages:
1: In function (pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,  :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In function (pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,  :
  argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Can anyone fix this for me?

---

EDIT: I read all around SO and R doc on this subject for over a day and couldn't find anything... then when I post it I think of searching for '[r] translation table' and I find *xlate*. Which is not mentioned anywhere in the *grep/sub/gsub* documentation.

1. Is there anything in *`base/gsubfn/data.table`* etc. to allow me to write one search-and-replacement instruction? (like a dictionary or translation table)
2. Can you improve my clunky syntax to be call-by-reference to tr? (mustn't create temp copy of entire df)

---

EDIT2: my best effort after reading around was:

The dictionary approach (*[xlate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353736/translation-recoding-error-in-r)*) might be a partial answer to, but this is more than a simple translation table since the regex must be terminal (e.g. '_14$').

I could use *gsub()* or *strsplit()* to split on '_' then do my *xlate* translation on the last component, then *paste()* them back together. Looking for a cleaner 1/2-line idiom.

Or else I just use walls of *gsub()s*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wall of `gsub` could be always replace by `for-loop`. And you can write it as a function:

```
renamer <- function(x, pattern, replace) {
    for (i in seq_along(pattern))
            x <- gsub(pattern[i], replace[i], x)
    x
}

names(tr) <- renamer(
     names(tr),
     sprintf('_%s$', c('1','14','22','50','52','57','76','1018','2001','3301','6005')),
     sprintf('_%s' , c('R','I', 'P', 'O', 'C', 'D', 'M', 'L',   'S',   'K',   'G'))
)
```

And I found `sprintf` more useful than `paste` for creation this kind of strings.

Comment: By saying `sprintf` is more useful than `paste` for creating these kind of strings, I presume you meant because we can directly give it vector of integer?

Comment: @smci I was thinking about string format: you know what is the pattern looking at first argument of `sprintf`. In `paste` with many elements sometimes it's hard to find how results will look like.

Comment: @smci But yes - feeding it by mixed types (numeric and character) is another advantage.

Comment: Good points, you might like to edit them into your answer. Most important for me is that we can directly parameterize `pattern=vector(int)`.

Comment: This was very useful, I see that you have to explicitly return x for it to work. How would this be extended to work over a list of data.frames that all need the same replacement patterns?

Answer (score 1):

The question predates the boom of the `tidyverse` but this is easily solved with the `c(pattern1 = replacement1)` option in `stringr::str_replace_all`.

```r
tr <- data.frame("whatevs_1" = NA, "something_52" = NA)

tr
#>   whatevs_1 something_52
#> 1        NA           NA

patterns <- sprintf('_%s$', c('1','14','22','50','52','57','76','1018','2001','3301','6005'))
replacements <- sprintf('_%s' , c('R','I', 'P', 'O', 'C', 'D', 'M', 'L',   'S',   'K',   'G'))
                        
names(replacements) <- patterns

names(tr) <- stringr::str_replace_all(names(tr), replacements)

tr
#>   whatevs_R something_C
#> 1        NA          NA
```

And of course, this particular case can benefit from `dplyr`

```r
dplyr::rename_all(tr, stringr::str_replace_all, replacements)
#>   whatevs_R something_C
#> 1        NA          NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *`do.call()`* nearly does it, it objects to differing arg lengths. I think I need to nest *`do.call()`* inside *`apply()`*, like in [apply function to elements over a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085110/apply-function-to-elements-over-a-list).

But I need a partial *`do.call()`* over pattern and replace.

This is all starting to make a wall of gsub(..., fixed=TRUE) look like a more efficient idiom, if flabby code.

```
pattern <- paste('_', c('1','14','22','50'), '$', sep='')
replace <- paste('_', c('R','I', 'P', 'O'),       sep='')
do.call(gsub, list(pattern, replace, names(tr)))
Warning messages:
1: In function (pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,  :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In function (pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,  :
  argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```