# base R alternative for stringr::str_replace_all with c(pattern1 = replacement1) option

Tags: r, regex, stringr

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455318/perform-multiple-search-and-replaces-on-the-colnames-of-a-dataframe) was seeking a similar answer probably before `stringr::str_replace_all` had that option (or was well known). I'm copying the gist of my answer below, using `str_replace_all`.

```r
tr <- c("whatevs_1", "something_52", "whatevs_1something_52")

tr
#> [1] "whatevs_1"             "something_52"          "whatevs_1something_52"

patterns <- sprintf('_%s$', c('1','14','22','50','52','57','76','1018','2001','3301','6005'))
replacements <- sprintf('_%s' , c('R','I', 'P', 'O', 'C', 'D', 'M', 'L',   'S',   'K',   'G'))
                        
names(replacements) <- patterns

stringr::str_replace_all(tr, replacements)
#> [1] "whatevs_R"            "something_C"          "whatevs_1something_C"
```

How would you achieve the above in base R?

The best option provided is a for loop. Just wondering if anyone had thought of a better alternative in the meantime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use a `for` loop with `gsub` from `base R` as the arguments are not vectorized i.e. `?gsub`

> pattern - If a character vector of length 2 or more is supplied, the first element is used with a warning. Missing values are allowed except for regexpr, gregexpr and regexec.

> replacement - If a character vector of length 2 or more is supplied, the first element is used with a warning. If NA, all elements in the result corresponding to matches will be set to NA.

Therefore, a `for` loop with recursive assignment may be the better option

```
for(i in seq_along(patterns)) tr <- gsub(patterns[i], replacements[i], tr)

tr
#[1] "whatevs_R"            "something_C"          "whatevs_1something_C"
```