# Is there a way to replace a group of strings with another group if strings via dplyr and stringr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I have reproduced a simple version of my problem. I essentially want to replace the English words in the statement column with the Spanish equivalent, for all statements.

```
library(tidyverse)
english <- c('hello','world','my','name', 'is')
spanish <- c('hola','mundo','mi','nombre', 'es')
statement <-c('Hello my name is john doe',' hello world','my name is world','hello john, my world is','jane is my world ')

df <- data.frame(english,spanish,statement)  
df
```

I tried

```
df %>% 
  str_replace_all(statement, c(df$english), c(df$spanish))
```

and

```
str_replace_all(statement, c(df$english), c(df$spanish)).
```

The second try got me closer to my answer. Only one answer was replaced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a super-simple solution, `str_replace_all` takes a named vector and automatically matches everything up:

```r
library(tidyverse)
english <- c('hello','world','my','name', 'is')
spanish <- c('hola','mundo','mi','nombre', 'es')
statement <-c('Hello my name is john doe',' hello world','my name is world','hello john, my world is','jane is my world ')

names(spanish) <- english

str_replace_all(statement, spanish)
#> [1] "Hello mi nombre es john doe" " hola mundo"                
#> [3] "mi nombre es mundo"          "hola john, mi mundo es"     
#> [5] "jane es mi mundo "
```

Answer (score 3):

In base R, you can use `gsub` in a for loop (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65571314/13460602)):

```r
tr <- statement
for(i in seq_along(english)) tr <- gsub(english[i], spanish[i], tr, ignore.case = TRUE)

# > tr
# [1] "hola mi nombre es john doe" " hola mundo"               
# [3] "mi nombre es mundo"         "hola john, mi mundo es"    
# [5] "jane es mi mundo "
```

---

Or with `match`:

```r
data.frame(statement = statement) |> 
  mutate(trad = lapply(strsplit(statement, " "), \(x) 
                       ifelse(is.na(match(tolower(x), english)), 
                              x, 
                              spanish[match(tolower(x), english)]) |> 
                         paste(collapse = " ")))

#                   statement                       trad
# 1 Hello my name is john doe hola mi nombre es john doe
# 2               hello world                 hola mundo
# 3          my name is world         mi nombre es mundo
# 4   hello john, my world is     hola john, mi mundo es
# 5         jane is my world            jane es mi mundo
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying :

```
library(tidyverse)
english <- c("hello", "world", "my", "name", "is")
spanish <- c("hola", "mundo", "mi", "nombre", "es")
statement <- c("Hello my name is john doe", " hello world", "my name is world", "hello john, my world is", "jane is my world ")


df <- data.frame(english, spanish, statement)
rowwise(df) |> mutate(
  replaced_stat = str_replace_all(
    statement, fixed(english,
      ignore_case = TRUE
    ) # or false depending ...
    , spanish
  )
)
```

but its possible you want something else

Comment: This is a great approach, though doesnt work in the instance with a comma (see the fourth line). Unfortunately I'm not savvy enough with stringr to know how to fix that. :)

Comment: Im not sure I understand the comment ? the fourth line is the phrase 'hello john, my world is' , and the word to potentially substitute is name > nombre, but name isnt in the phrase. perhaps the phrase itself was meant to have been "hello john, my name is" ?

Comment: Whoops, apologies - I was indeed unclear! The fourth line of the *output*, not the code does not translate it, and leaves it as "hello john, my world is" - see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APJfZ.png) to see how the output looks like on my machine (with the purple underlines indicating words not translated). Again, great approach though!

Comment: it seems the english and spanish dictionaries have no rowwise relationship with the 'statements' , I'm afraid that implied relationship misled me; Therefore you should prefer  Andy Baxters solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/77600952/11726436